# Deserialize JSON array with different values type with kotlinx.serialization library

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, kotlinx.serialization

I'm trying to deserialize following String:

```kotlin
 val stringJson = "{\"decomposed\":[\", \",{\"id\":4944372,\"name\":\"Johny\",\"various\":false,\"composer\":false,\"genres\":[]}]}"
```

Deserialization works fine with following code

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Artist(
    val decomposed: JsonArray
)

fun main() {
    val jsonString = "{\"decomposed\":[\", \",{\"id\":4944372,\"name\":\"Johny\",\"various\":false,\"composer\":false,\"genres\":[]}]}"
    println(Json.decodeFromString<Artist>(jsonString))
}
```

But I want to do something like

```kotlin
@Serializable
class Decomposed {
    @Serializable
    class DecomposedClassValue(val value: DecomposedClass)

    @Serializable
    class StringValue(val value: String)
}


@Serializable
data class DecomposedClass(
    val id: Long? = null,
    val name: String? = null,
    val various: Boolean? = null,
    val composer: Boolean? = null,
    val genres: JsonArray? = null
)

@Serializable
data class Artist(
    val decomposed: List<Decomposed>
)

fun main() {
    val jsonString = "{\"decomposed\":[\", \",{\"id\":4944372,\"name\":\"Johny\",\"various\":false,\"composer\":false,\"genres\":[]}]}"
    println(Json.decodeFromString<Artist>(jsonString))
}
```

But `kotlinx.serialization` expectedly fails with `JsonDecodingException: Unexpected JSON token at offset 15: Expected '{, kind: CLASS'`
And I can't figure out how can I rewrite my `Decomposed` so deserialization work. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Is it possible to tweak format of JSON or it is a hard requirment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called [polymorphic deserialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md).
It requires target classes of deserialization to have a common superclass (preferrably sealed):

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Artist(
    val decomposed: List<Decomposed>
)

@Serializable
sealed class Decomposed

@Serializable
class StringValue(val value: String) : Decomposed() //Can't add superclass to String, so we have to create a wrapper class which we could make extend Decomposed

@Serializable
data class DecomposedClass(
    val id: Long? = null,
    val name: String? = null,
    val various: Boolean? = null,
    val composer: Boolean? = null,
    val genres: JsonArray? = null
) : Decomposed() //DecomposedClassValue is redundant, we may extend DecomposedClass from Decomposed directly
```

This will allow you to deserialize JSON of the following format:

```kotlin
val jsonString = "{\"decomposed\":[{\"type\":\"StringValue\", \"value\":\",\"}, {\"type\":\"DecomposedClass\", \"id\":4944372,\"name\":\"Johny\",\"various\":false,\"composer\":false,\"genres\":[]}]}"
```

Since there is no [class descriminator](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#class-discriminator) in original JSON, serialization library can't determine the actual serializer which should be used to deserialize Kotlin class. You will have to write custom [JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#content-based-polymorphic-deserialization) and wire it to `Decomposed` class; also you have to write custom serializer for `StringValue` class, as it is represented in JSON as a `String`, not a JSONObject with a `value` field of `String` type:

```kotlin
object DecomposedSerializer : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<Decomposed>(Decomposed::class) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement) = when {
        element is JsonPrimitive -> StringValue.serializer()
        else -> DecomposedClass.serializer()
    }
}

object StringValueSerializer : KSerializer<StringValue> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = buildClassSerialDescriptor("StringValue")

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): StringValue {
        require(decoder is JsonDecoder)
        val element = decoder.decodeJsonElement()
        return StringValue(element.jsonPrimitive.content)
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: StringValue) {
        encoder.encodeString(value.value)
    }
}

@Serializable(with = DecomposedSerializer::class)
sealed class Decomposed

@Serializable(with = StringValueSerializer::class)
class StringValue(val value: String) : Decomposed()
```

This will allow you to deserialize JSON of original format.